# Why can't I summarize all the properties of an array?

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to summarize all the properties `price` of the array `this.hamburgers` in order to find their total amount and in the future to find the average cost of the order I want to transfer to `localStorage`.

**But when I try to get all the properties of `price` in the method `sumHamburgers()` I get the result: "undefined"**.

```js
class Magazine {
  constructor() {
    this.hamburgers = [];
  }

  sumHamburgers() {
    return this.hamburgers.map(el => el.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
  }

  hamburgersAvgN() {
    return this.sumHamburgers() / Hamburger.counter;
  }

  toStorage() {
    let serialCounter = JSON.stringify(Hamburger.counter);
    let serialAvgN = JSON.stringify(this.hamburgersAvgN());
    return localStorage.setItem(['orders', 'avg'], [`number of orders: ${serialCounter}`, ` average check: ${serialAvgN} UAH`]);
  }
}

class Hamburger {
  constructor(size, ...stuffing) {
    this.size = size;
    this.stuffing = stuffing;
    this.toppingArr = [];
    this.counter = ++Hamburger.counter;
  }

  calculatePrice() {
    const stuffingCost = this.stuffing.map(el => el.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
    let allCost;
    if (this.toppingArr.length === 0) {
      return allCost = this.size.price + stuffingCost;
    } else {
      const toppingCost = this.toppingArr.map(el => el.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
      return allCost = this.size.price + stuffingCost + toppingCost;
    }
  }
}

Hamburger.counter = 0;

Hamburger.small = {
  name: 'small',
  price: 10,
  kcal: 200
}

Hamburger.cheese = {
  name: 'cheese',
  price: 4,
  kcal: 10
}

Hamburger.meet = {
  name: ' meet',
  price: 40,
  kcal: 103
}

let magazine = new Magazine;
magazine.hamburgers.push(new Hamburger(Hamburger.small, Hamburger.meet));
magazine.hamburgers.push(new Hamburger(Hamburger.small, Hamburger.cheese));
magazine.hamburgers.push(new Hamburger(Hamburger.small, Hamburger.meet));

console.log(magazine.sumHamburgers());
```

Comment: Maybe somewhere in your json string is a non parseable value for Hambuger.counter

Comment: What is the input? What is the expected output?

Comment: when I call a method I don’t get the total amount of all the burgers, I get: "undefined"

Comment: Your snippet currently has a syntax error "*SyntaxError: missing : after property id*"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to call `el.caculatePrice()` instead of `el.price` which is not exist:

```js
class Magazine {
  constructor() {
    this.hamburgers = [];
  }

  sumHamburgers() {
    // My fix is here: `el.calculatePrice()` instead of `el.price`
    return this.hamburgers.map(el => el.calculatePrice()).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
  }

  hamburgersAvgN() {
    return this.sumHamburgers() / Hamburger.counter;
  }

  toStorage() {
    let serialCounter = JSON.stringify(Hamburger.counter);
    let serialAvgN = JSON.stringify(this.hamburgersAvgN());
    return localStorage.setItem(['orders', 'avg'], [`number of orders: ${serialCounter}`, ` average check: ${serialAvgN} UAH`]);
  }
}

class Hamburger {
  constructor(size, ...stuffing) {
    this.size = size;
    this.stuffing = stuffing;
    this.toppingArr = [];
    this.counter = ++Hamburger.counter;
  }

  calculatePrice() {
    const stuffingCost = this.stuffing.map(el => el.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
    let allCost;
    if (this.toppingArr.length === 0) {
      return allCost = this.size.price + stuffingCost;
    } else {
      const toppingCost = this.toppingArr.map(el => el.price).reduce((p, c) => p + c);
      return allCost = this.size.price + stuffingCost + toppingCost;
    }
  }
}

Hamburger.counter = 0;

Hamburger.small = {
  name: 'small',
  price: 10,
  kcal: 200
}

Hamburger.cheese = {
  name: 'cheese',
  price: 4,
  kcal: 10
}

Hamburger.meet = {
  name: 'meet',
  price: 40,
  kcal: 103
}

let magazine = new Magazine;
magazine.hamburgers.push(new Hamburger(Hamburger.small, Hamburger.meet));
magazine.hamburgers.push(new Hamburger(Hamburger.small, Hamburger.cheese));
magazine.hamburgers.push(new Hamburger(Hamburger.small, Hamburger.meet));

console.log(magazine.sumHamburgers());
```

Comment: and price located inside: size, tooping, stuffing

Comment: u can see how i add all property price in calculatePrice()  method,  in  sumHamburgers() i want add  result of calculatePrice every  gamburger

Comment: Did you run the code in my answer? the result is 30 (10 + 10 + 10). The fix is in line 8.

Comment: u code calc only property price  in "size", i  need calc all price of burger   to  next burger  for had  all cost of burgers.

Comment: every param have a price (size, stuffing, toppingArr), i calc  summ of this param in  calculatePrice (),  but its only for  one burger, in method sumHamburgers() i want find cost of all burger with all param's what they have

Comment: @IgorShvets ok I think I get you now, but you are missing some code in your example: where is the definition of `Hanburger.cheese` and `Hnamburger.meet`? put them in your example

Comment: @IgorShvets You should edit the question with additional information. I saw what you meant and edited my answer. have a look.